# What is the tangent space of $\mathbb{Z}$ at $\mathfrak{p}=(5)$?

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, affine-schemes, zariski-topology

What is the tangent space of the scheme $\text{Spec}\,\mathbb{Z}$ at the point $\mathfrak{p}= (5)$ ?

- the local ring of $\mathbb{Z}$ at $(5)$ is $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Z},5}=\mathbb{Z}_5$ the 5-adic numbers
- and the ring of regular functions is the set of functions $f \in \mathbb{Z}$ vanishing at $\mathfrak{p}=5$, so we have $m_{\text{Spec}\, \mathbb{Z}, (5)} = 5 \,\mathbb{Z}_5$.
- therefore the co-tangent space of $\mathbb{Z}$ at $\mathfrak{p}=(5)$ is $m_x/m_x^2 = 5 \mathbb{Z}_5 / 5^2 \mathbb{Z}_5 \simeq \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$.

Originally I had thought it would be $\mathbb{Q}_5^\times / (\mathbb{Q}_5^\times)^2$ but oddly $\mathbb{Q}_p$ doesn't factor anywhere into this discussion.

---

The localization of the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ at the place $(5)$ is $\mathfrak{m}_5=\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{5}]$, so perhaps the tangent space should be the quotient ring $\mathfrak{m}_5/\mathfrak{m}_5^2=\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{5}]/\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{5}]^2$.

Comment: The local ring of $\mathbb Z$ at $5$ is the ring of integers localized at the multiplicative set of non-multiples of $5$, not the $5$-adics.

Comment: @JohnBrevik when you have time can you put the details into an answer?

Comment: The localization of the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ at the place $(5)$ is obtained by inverting everything *not* in the prime ideal $(5)$, rather than by inverting a generator of that ideal. Inverting $5$, geometrically, has the effect of restricting to the open complement of the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The local ring $R$ is $\mathbb Z$ localized away from the prime ideal $5\mathbb Z$, *i.e.*, the set $\{q\in \mathbb Q:q=\frac{a}{b}$ for some $a,b\in \mathbb Z, (5,b)=1\}$. Its maximal ideal is $5R$, and its Zariski tangent space is the dual of $5R/25R$, a vector space over $\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z$ of dimension $1$.

Comment: So the local ring is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ with condition on the [height](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_ring), $|\cdot|_5$. I guess I mixed up the words "[localization](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_of_a_ring)" and "[completion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completion_(algebra))". Of course $p=5$ could have been any prime number, a "place".

Comment: @cactus314 Yes, and the Zariski tangent space is still the same ($R/\mathfrak m$ and $\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2$ don't change).